# Create Assembly is successful, nothing found in sys.assembly_modules

Tags: sql-server, integration, clr

First attempt at a CLR Integration, so I can use Regex tools.

I create the assembly:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLRegexTools
  FROM 'D:\CODE\SQLRegexTools\SQLRegexTools\bin\Release\SQLRegexTools.dll'
```

This succeeds, and the assembly appears in SELECT @ FROM sys.assemblies.

But there are no records returned to SELECT * FROM sys.Assembly_modules.

And when I try to CREATE FUNCTION to call one of the methods,

```
CREATE FUNCTION RegExMatch(@pattern varchar(max)
                            , @SearchIn varchar(max)
                            , @options int)
RETURNS varchar
 EXTERNAL NAME SQLRegexTools.Functions.RegExMatch
```

I get an error 'Msg 6505, Could not find Type "Functions" in assembly 'SQLRegexTools.'

The class name of the VB module is "Functions". Why is this called a type in the error, and why might I not be seeing anything in the modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when SQL Server is unable to resolve the name as provided. Try the snippet below to see if this resolves the issue.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RegExMatch(@pattern varchar(max)
                            , @SearchIn varchar(max)
                            , @options int)
RETURNS varchar
AS EXTERNAL NAME SQLRegexTools.[Functions].RegExMatch
```

The resolution of individual functions/methods for accessing native code is relatively indistinguishable from a multipart object name (e.g. a type).

An additional note is that native code that utilizing nested namespaces must fully qualify nested namespaces within the same pair of quotes. For example, if `RegExMatch` were located at `SQLRegexTools.A.B.C.RegExMatch`, you would reference this as `SQLRegexTools.[A.B.C].RegExMatch` when using it with `EXTERNAL NAME` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

That hits the answer Joey. Thank you.

There are several gotchas in this process I learned after much sleuthing and testing. They are often buried in long posts about the entire process, I will summarize here:

- As Joey explained, the fully qualified name is needed. To be more complete...

Example:

```
             1                 2                   3               4
```

[SQLRegexToolsASM].[SQLRegexToolsNS.RegexFunctionsClass].RegExMatch

1. This is the assembly name in the CREATE ASSEMBLY step.
2. This is the Root Namespace from the properties of the assembly project. If you declared a namespace or two, they must be included in their proper order, after this item and before item 3 in this list. Observe all these namespaces are enclosed in their own square brackets.

assembly.[rootnamespace.namespace.namespace].classname.methodname”

3. This is the Class Name you assigned to the class, maybe like this

   Public Class RegexFunctionsClass
4. The name of the method defined in your VB or C# assembly.